# ActiveMQ, timestamp for broker receiving the message to send

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Ok, as per ActiveMQ docs, it appears that Message.getJMSTimestamp() returns time that client claims it sent the message (with its local clock). And that there is supposedly property "JMSActiveMQBrokerInTime" that is added to Message (see http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html).
However, trying to access it on an ActiveMQ 4.1.2 installation gives an error.

Does anyone know if this is something that was only added in 5.0 or later? Or is there some other explanation as to where it might have disappeared? Message.getPropertyNames() returns empty enumeration, which could indicate that nothing gets through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that's added in 5.x version. If you cannot upgrade, you can consider creating a plugin like TimeStamp plugin (http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html) as I think that is as well 5.x only and sync you times on the broker side.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I hope to convince people in charge of maintenance to upgrade -- from what I heard, upgrade to 5.0 makes lots of sense all around. But it is a production system, so it will take time.

Comment: What's the equivalent of "JMSActiveMQBrokerInTime" in ActiveMQ Artemis?